# Find the subarray within an array (containing at least TWO number) which has the largest sum

Tags: algorithm

Find the subarray within an array (**containing at least TWO number**) which has the largest sum. 
For example, given the array [-2,-1,-3,-4,-1], 
the contiguous subarray [-2,-1] has the largest sum = -3. 
try to do it in O(n) time 
Followup, if input is stream, how to solve it 
public int maxSubArray(int[] nums) {}

Comment: Please show us some efforts, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For an Array of size (N). Let us call it A
You can create another array B where you will store the sum so Far.
Now traverse through the parent Array.

```
    int max = Integer.MIN;
B[0] = A[0];
    for(i=1;i<A.length;i++)
    {
    if(A[i] > 0){
    B[i]=B[i-1] + A[i];
    }else if(A[i]+B[i-1] > max){
    B[i] = A[i]+B[i-1]
    max = A[i]+B[i-1]
    }
    else{
    B[i] = A[i];
    }
```

Now the max number in Array B has the max possible sum of the consecutive sub Array but you don't know the Sub Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kadane's Algorithm in modified fashion.

You can find Kadane' Algorithm [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/). (You will store the ends of the subarray too).

How can we modify it?

-> Just keep in track of the window size you are taking i.e. **RIGHT-LEFT>=1**

I think this should help for all set of numbers including negative.

Still for all negative numbers (which you can check in an O(n) go). Just loop **FROM o to N : maximum = max(arr[i]+arr[i+1],maximum);** 
Just to ensure if the case gets covered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
int maxvalue = int.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
    int value = 0;
    for (int x = i; x <= j; x++)
      value += array[x];
    if (value > maxvalue)
      maxvalue = value;
  }
return maxvalue;
```